# Where to store cookies safely on Linux

Tags: php, linux, security, curl, cookies

I'm running *curl* from PHP and I want to use cookies.

Curl, in PHP, accept the option **COOKIEJAR** that specifies the location where to save the cookie.

I wanted to set it to

```
curl_setopt_array(
  CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR => sys_get_temp_dir() . '/cookie.txt'
  ...
);
```

My first thought was to put them into the */tmp* folder but then I wondered about the security implications.

I know that absolute security doesn't exist but, where should a cookie be stored, in a Linux environment, to be reasonably safe?

Comment: Who do you want to protect it against? For example, you cannot safely protect it from the user that has superuser privileges?

Comment: As a rule of thumb: if you do not want that a file can be seen or read by local users, then put it into a directory where only you yourself (your account) has got access privileges to. Not more, not less.

Comment: @zerkms it is quite obvious that the question matter just when a malicious user doesn't have privileged access. The question came up cause /tmp is a sort of _"shared"_ directory, and maybe there is a better directory where to put some sensible information (I'm not an expert about what a skilled cracker could provoke, relying on a directory where multiple users have access), even without privileged. I mainly worry about the sticky bit mechanism, cause am not aware of potential issues with it.

Comment: @Kamafeather: you **have not** defined what "malicious user" is. Hence it's not possible to answer how to protect unless you state who you want to protect it from. Does malicious user have access to *your* account? You made a great statement that you understand that there is no "absolute security" then asked about one.

Comment: @arkascha yes is a good rule. I wanted to use the _/tmp_ folder cause that is a directory automatically flushed, while saving the cookie (let's say) under _/home/username/_ would require to manually delete the file (if/when needed)

Comment: "that is a directory automatically flushed" --- is it? By what and how frequently?

Comment: No, I assume that I cannot protect from a user that has access to my account or more privileges than me. On the 'how frequently' is relative (more frequently will not anyway guarantee me more safety). I care mainly on possible exploits or vulnerabilities that don't directly involve acquisition of privileged rights).

Comment: @Kamafeather: I'm confused. You said that you chose `/tmp` because if is automatically flushed, now you say it's not. :-S That's weird

Comment: `/tmp` obviously is an insecure place insofar as you are concerned about other being able to access the file. You can still use restrictive rights for the file itself, but it will be visible to others. This is not the case in a more restrictively protected directory. A cleanup procedure of such a directory would consist of a single line cron tab entry.

Comment: @arkascha is there any directory that "usually" is preferred for this kind of temporary storage? I guess somewhere under the _/home/<user>/_ directory; but would like to know if there is some conventional or "usually preferred" folder for this kind of stuff.

Comment: @zerkms the 'No' and the first sentence were referred to your previous question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Linux everything is file and controlled by operation system filesystem.

you dont have to store a specific file in a weird location because of security since even ssl keys store in `/etc/ssl/private/` for example.

the only Strong mechanism to gain the security is to directly specify the Ownership and `chmod` of the file to be not accessible by others.

```
chmod -c 700
```

is the most powerful with chown to user.

then protected users passwords.

### Another Security Layer

you can add encryption and decryption for the file, but you have to save **the key** some where on the disk and protect with **File Ownership** mechanism.

Comment: So the question should not be about "where" to store safely but "how" to store safely ;)